# How to create a dictionary and store values for the values in c#

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary for the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <groups>
        <group>
            <data>Open</data>
            <aggregation>5</aggregation>
        </group>
    </groups>
```

I want my dictionary to get the values as:

Open,5

Please note that 'Open' is fetched from `<data>Open</data>` and '5' is fetched from `<aggregation>5</aggregation>`.

My current code is as follows:

```
foreach (XmlNode group in Bugsagg)
{
    XmlNode data = group.SelectSingleNode(".//data");
    XmlNode aggregate = group.SelectSingleNode(".//aggregation");

    if (Dict_Aggregate.ContainsKey(data.InnerText))
    {
        Dict_Aggregate[data.InnerText]++;
    }
    else
    {
        Dict_Aggregate.Add(data.InnerText, 1);
    }
```

I am not getting the desired response. Please suggest where i am doing wrong.Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the respective output from the xml in dictionary using c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755688/how-to-get-the-respective-output-from-the-xml-in-dictionary-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @I4V At least this one got an answer.

Comment: Do not repost questions, you can _edit_ to improve them. This one is more legible then the prvious one so this one should stand.

Comment: @HenkHolterman agreed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use XElement and LINQ to XML.
You should add

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

on top of your code. Then use the following

```
string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""yes""?><groups><group><data>Open</data><aggregation>5</aggregation></group></groups>";

XElement xe =  XElement.Parse(xml);

Dictionary<string,string> d =
xe.Elements("group")
.ToDictionary 
(
    x=>(string)x.Element("data"),      //Key Selector
    z=>(string)z.Element("aggregation")//Value Selector
);
```

Some people might also suggest to use an XDocument as you provide a fully qualified xml with declaration etc:

```
XDocument xd = XDocument.Parse(xml);

Dictionary<string,string> d =   
xd.Root.Elements("group")
.ToDictionary 
(
    x=>(string)x.Element("data"),      //Key Selector
    z=>(string)z.Element("aggregation")//Value Selector
);
```

Comment: You should declare `xe` first. And I would use `(string)XElement` explicit casting instead of `Value` property.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I had declared it in my code in LINQPad, but obviously i forgot to paste it here :). I confess I didn't know i could just use a cast... Do you think it is better than using the value?

Comment: And it would be much better with an `Dictionary<string,string> d = ...`

Comment: @jyparask ..is this code creating a dictionary for the respective output.I wonder how to specify the dictionary to which i am creating the respective output.

Comment: @HenkHolterman You are very right. I am using LINQPad and Dump and i don't need to define the left part... I keep forgetting that. Thanks.

Comment: @user2764162 It will create a Dictionary<string,string> d (see the updated solution) that will have a Key:Open and a Value:5

Comment: @jyparask `(string)XElement` will not throw `NullReferenceException` when element is not found.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Well, it certainly is nice learning something new...though i should have known that.

Comment: @jyparask `(int)XElement` will throw an exception for `null` element, `(int?)XElement` will work just fine. You can find list of all supported types you can cast `XElement` to on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986933.aspx)